# python serialization of objects on appengine

Tags: python, xml, google-app-engine

I wanted to serialize an object in xml for a client application from app-engine. I started using the django 1.2 serialization described here:

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/serialization/

```
from django.core import serializers
....

data = serializers.serialize("xml", TestObject.all())
```

It raises the following error:

```
raise base.SerializationError("Non-model object (%s) encountered during serialization" %   type(obj))
SerializationError: Non-model object () encountered during serialization
```

which I assume is django not liking the app-engine db.Model objects. Is there another way to go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you need the XML to be in a specific format? All `db.Model` objects have a built-in [`to_xml()` method](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/modelclass.html#Model_to_xml) that conforms to Atom & GData specs. Is that useful?

Comment: Cheers - I hadn't noticed that function. It only solves half the problem though as I need to de-serialize the object too.

Comment: You should still be able to use any of the SAX or DOM-based parsers that come with Python, right?